# Form not showing error messages (Rails 3 project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

My submit form is not showing error messages...when I fill it out incorrectly and submit, it just refreshes. It should show error messages - see attached code -- but for some reason it isn't. Not sure why this is happening.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Faisal

**_FORM.HTML.ERB**

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
I am a <%= f.text_field :title %> getting married in <%= f.text_field :job %> in <%= f.text_field :location %>, and looking for a wedding photographer. My budget is <%= f.text_field :salary %>.
</div>

<form>
<div id="first_button">
<button type="button" id="your_button" class="btn span6 large">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="real_form">
<%=  recaptcha_tags %>
<button type="submit" class="btn span6 large">Submit</button>
</div>​

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#real_form").hide(); //this will hide the `real_form` div on page load
    $("#your_button").click(function() {
        $("#real_form").show(); // this will show the `real_form` on clicking of `any_button` button
        $("#first_button").hide(); 
    });
});
</script>
<% end %>
```

**POSTS CONTROLLER**

```
def create
@post = Post.new

respond_to do |format|
  if verify_recaptcha
      if @post.save
          format.html { redirect_to :action=> "index"}
          format.json { render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  else
          flash[:message] = 'Please try filling out Recaptcha again' #added to confirm an error is present
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.json { render :json => @post }
  end
end
end
```

**POST MODEL**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, :job, :location, :salary, :presence => true 
validates :salary, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 1} 
end
```

**Posts > New.Html.Erb file**

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<h1>Find wedding photographers with ease.</h1>
<br>
<p>Post your needs and sit back and wait to get responses.</p>
<br>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= flash[:message] %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your form show all errors, there might be another problem prevent saving models. Make sure you can save models in rails console.

Comment: Open rails console `rails c` create a new model `p = Post.new ...` and save it `p.save`. As console is verbose there is a chance to find out the problem, but there are cases in witch this don't help (an example is database problems).

Comment: The post does not save even when I use Rails console...see error message posted above.

Comment: ok it is saving properly now, but still not showing error messages...that is the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Devise or another authentication library.

You might need to put an authenticity token in your forms (although that would log you out rather just redirect, but it might be the behavior if you don't have an auth library)

You should also use `form_for @post` so that your inputs get named correctly for your new function (that would put in the auth token for you).

You problem might also be in your model, you might have to whitelist the attributes sent by your form.

Comment: not using any authentication library. I have added my posts model above as well. What specific changes should I make?

Comment: try `attr_accessible :title, :job, :location, :salary`

Comment: also try creating a record without putting params in new. If another error occurs, then it's something else.

Comment: thanks. so it shows error messages now, but only when recaptcha is filled out correctly. if recaptcha is left blank or incorrectly filled, then it doesn't show any errors...how to fix this?

Comment: this is your first mention of recaptcha, but i'd say recaptcha errors are not `@post.errors` just put a standard notice in there.

Comment: tried removing params for new, did not change anything...still see the errors only when recaptcha is filled out properly..

Comment: just to clarify, the problem is not with recaptcha errors, don't care about those - its the form errors. The form errors ONLY show if recaptcha is filled out correctly. If recaptcha is left blank, or incorrect, then the form errors do not show. you can try it here at: http://weddoo.heroku.com to see what i mean...thanks!!

Comment: if recaptcha is failing it's not doing any further validation. I'd create a `post` object first to see if it validates and then if the recaptcha pass, run save.

Comment: ok, done...see edited posts controller above. for some reason, it doesn't show the flash error for bad recaptcha...i have put the tag in application.html.erb...is the controller ok now, or am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: that looks fine, so when you fail recaptcha + validation do you get both sets of messages.

Comment: if both recapatcha + form validation fail, i still see no error messages. the only time i see an error message is if recaptcha is OK, but form validation fails. could it be a sessions error? if so how to fix? thank you!!

Comment: also just to add, i have placed the flash:message tag in the views>posts>new.html.erb file, i think this is the right place for it.